# Problem building a complete binary tree of height 'h' in Python

Tags: python

Here is my code. The complete binary tree has 2^k nodes at depth k.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):
        # initializes the data members
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data


root = Node(data_root)

def create_complete_tree():
        row = [root]

        for i in range(h):

            newrow = []
            for node in row:
                left = Node(data1)  
                right = Node(data2)  

                node.left = left
                node.right = right

                newrow.append(left)
                newrow.append(right)


            row = copy.deepcopy(newrow)



def traverse_tree(node):
        if node == None:
            return
        else:
            traverse_tree(node.left)
            print node.data
            traverse_tree(node.right)

create_complete_tree()

print 'Node traversal'

traverse_tree(root)
```

The tree traversal only gives the data of root and its children. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a question? What's wrong with your current code? Please elaborate. Explain what kind of tree you're hoping to construct (you could make an ascii drawing of it) and also post the tree that *IS* being created instead. I ask for such details since it happens quite often that people mix the definitions up of "complete", "full", "balanced"... binary trees.

Comment: Yes I am not getting the right output

Comment: @ Bart - ok...I understand now

Comment: @Jack, okay, but are you going to add the additional information to your post, or is this *as good as it gets*? :)

Comment: @ Bart yep that is why I added the beginner tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that you are using deepcopy on the temporary list.  Consider what happens each iteration:

1. Your initial root gets inspected, and child nodes get created
2. These child nodes are placed in newrow
3. **Copies** of these child nodes are copied into row for the next iteration.

This means the subsequent iteration will not be mutating the nodes you created (and which root.left and root.right points to), but copies of them, leaving the originals in their current state (with `None` for `.left` and `.right`)